# Formatting based on cell value and surrounding rows

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have an excel spreadsheet of a BOM that I'm trying to conditionally format.  The data is laid out such that column A is the item number. Since the BOM has alternates, there are repeated numbers.  I want to go through the spreadsheet and for each item number, find the item with "Active" in column F and highlight them green and hide the alternates on the other rows. If there is no "active" item, I want to highlight the items as yellow and keep them displayed.  I have the current vba script which does the highlighting. If you look at the example data I basically want a single line for each item number which shows the active part, but if there is no active part, to show the historical or discontinued parts in yellow

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim icolor As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim sheetname As String
sheetname = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
With Worksheets(sheetname)
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For Each cell In Range("F1:F" & lastrow)
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case Is = "Active"
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Case Is = "Status"
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Case Is = ""
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Else
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End Select
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Here's a screenshot of some sample data:**
[image: Data Sample]

Comment: Can you please provide an image of your data as well as your expected result? That may help others in understanding how everything works and what you're looking for.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot but I can't embed the picture due to a my reputation being too low

Comment: I went ahead and edited it for you. Once my edit is approved you should see it embedded. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Why do you want to do that on every selection change? Shouldn't it be `Worksheet_Change`? Since the cells in col F doesn't change automatically.

Comment: The excel spreadsheet is an output of a database so I wanted to be able to copy the vba script to each spreadsheet so it would run once when I changed the selection. That way I make sure I don’t change a cell value to get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the row height to zero to hide it

```
cell.EntireRow.RowHeight = 0
```

But don't forget to reset it in the other two cases

```
 cell.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check to see if the cell value is NULL as well as ""